# Error while running "make" command for running darknet-master

Tags: darknet

```
PS C:\darknet-master> make
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname, ...) failed.
Makefile:22: pipe: No error
chmod +x *.sh
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, chmod +x *.sh, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:191: setchmod] Error 2
```

I am using windows for executing darknet, but I don't know why the chmod command is wrong. I already used the same pattern in ubuntu and in ubuntu it's working without any problem. So, can anyone please give me solutions? Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because Windows doesn't have `chmod` installed. And files on Windows filesystems (NTFS, exFAT, FAT32) don't have the same concept of permissions as Unix - rwx (read write execute). So installing chmod is moot too.

Even if you did install `chmod`, based on the command `chmod +x *.sh` Make is trying to make all the files with the *.sh extension executable. `.sh` is typically used with shell or bash files, which can also not be executed on Windows because `bash` needs to be installed.

What you need is to use one of the Windows-specific methods listed in the documention

- [using vcpkg](https://github.com/kongzhiyou/darknet-master#how-to-compile-on-windows-using-vcpkg)
- [manually in the legacy way](https://github.com/kongzhiyou/darknet-master#how-to-compile-on-windows-legacy-way)